# open a specific activity from firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I integrated firebase notification to my application but I would like to send a notification that opens a specific activity and does what I schedule to do, not just opening the App. like a notification that will push the user to visit Google play store on clicking it.

I saw a code [Firebase console: How to specify click_action for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111339/firebase-console-how-to-specify-click-action-for-notifications) which I used but am getting an error to initialize variable cls. I tried to resolve by defining cls=null,  to clear error. It fails to open my specified activity using the click_action

```
public class ClickActionHelper { 
    public static void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context){ 
        Class cls=null; 
        try { 
            cls = Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
            //means you made a wrong input in firebase console 
        } 
        Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
        i.putExtras(extras); context.startActivity(i); 
    }     
}
```

please am I getting anything wrong? How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 22):

**If you want to open your app and perform a specific action [while backgrounded], set click_action in the notification payload and map it to an intent filter in the Activity you want to launch. For example, set click_action to OPEN_ACTIVITY_1 to trigger an intent filter like the following:**

As suggested in FCM docs, ask backend to send JSON data in the form like this,

```
{
    "to": "some_device_token",

    "content_available": true,
    "notification": {
        "title": "hello",
        "body": "yo",
        "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" // for intent filter in your activity
    },

    "data": {
        "extra": "juice"
    }
}
```

and in your mainfest file add intent-filter for your activity as below

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

When you click the notification, it will open the app and go straight to activity that you define in click_action, in this case "OPEN_ACTIVTY_1". And inside that activity you can get the data by :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();// add these lines of code to get data from notification
String someData = b.getString("someData");
```

Check out below links for more help:

[Firebase FCM notifications click_action payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407366/firebase-fcm-notifications-click-action-payload)

[Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

[Firebase console: How to specify click_action for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111339/firebase-console-how-to-specify-click-action-for-notifications)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been around for a while, but I wanted to show my solution anyway. its much simpler than those presented. so now I'm wandering if its bad practice. but it works:
I use the payload json object to store an integer :

```
JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");
int destination = payload.getInt("click_action");
```

then I just use a simple switch statement to launch the right activity based on the integer result:

```
Intent resultIntent;
switch(destination){
    case 1:
        resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfileActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        break;
    default:
        resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        break;
}
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".design.NotificationActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NotificationActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

        $ url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        $token = "";
        $serverKey = '';
        $title = "your title";
        $body = "mesaage";
        $notification = array('title' =>$title ,
        'body' => $body, 
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => '1',
        'click_action' => 'NotificationActivity'
        );
        $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
        $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        //Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ ch);
        //Close request
        if ($response === FALSE) {
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch)
```