# how to handle FCM background state in the android

Tags: android

In the android, FCM  notification comes and app is in the background state and when tapped, it redirects to Default Activity (LoginActivity) but I want to navigate to specified activity (HomeActivity).

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_1");
    notification/*.setSound(soundUri)*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_photo_camera_black_24dp)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
            0);

    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have done

Comment: This code is perfect some other coding mistake you have.

Comment: when i send "notification json", it opens default activity when app is in the background
"notification": { "body": "Hello data", "title": "This is test title data.", "message": "This is test message. data" }

when i send "data json", it opens particular activity when app is in the background
"data": { "body": "Hello data", "title": "This is test title data.", "message": "This is test message. data" }

Comment: Where this code is written?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to pass an activity parameter from the api/json part. from your app side you will check for the activity nave and than open accordingly

see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665485/6442746 for more insights.

Answer (score 0):

You should send a format is Data Message to handle notification in onMessageReceived when the app is background or foreground
[image]

When received data in onMessageReceived(), you can show notification and direct to your activity.