# FCM Notification onclick does not open desired activity

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have tried almost every solution posted here and combination of every flag but it is not working.

Following are use cases in which i am having problems.

1) When i am in application **FCM** notification opens my desired activity.
Data is passed to `onNewIntent` in main activity. It works fine when application is foreground.

2) When in background mode(presssing home button) after clicking on notification it launches new instance of my application even though i have specified `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in manifest file to my main activity but i don't know what is happening here. Desired Activity i want to open here is **`RateEventActivity`**

the strange thing happening here is that `NotificationActivity` and  `ProfileActivity` are working perfectly even when application is in background mode but **`RateEventActivity`** is producing all the problem as i described above. Most of application code is written by someone else  i am working on `RateEevent` module so i don't know what i am missing here?

Intents are lost somewhere (not passed to `mainActivty` on create) when i am clicking notification from background mode in **`RateEventActivity`** scenario.

i have also tried passing unique id to my pending intent but no luck. I have put lot of time and effort to solve this but failing every time

**here is my FCM code**

```
  private void createNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Log.v("Notification Title", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notificationUser")) {
        intent.putExtra("notificationUser", remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationUser"));
    } else if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notificationId")) {
        intent.putExtra("notificationId", remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationId"));
    } else if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("event")) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Event Feedback")) {


            Log.v("Notification Event", remoteMessage.getData().get("event"));
            intent.putExtra("eventId", remoteMessage.getData().get("event"));
        }


    }


    //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(notification.getBody()))
                    .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Main Activity Code `onCreate` Method

```
   if (getIntent().hasExtra("notificationId")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationId", getIntent().getStringExtra("notificationId"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("user")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userId", getIntent().getStringExtra("user"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("eventId")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RateEventActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("eventId", getIntent().getStringExtra("eventId"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**My Manifest File**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/HomeTheme" />

<activity
        android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

 <activity
        android:name=".activities.NotificationActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="Notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

<activity
        android:name=".activities.RateEventActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="Rate Users"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       />
```

Comment: are you getting this log ` Log.v("Notification Event", remoteMessage.getData().get("event"));`??

Comment: yes i am getting data from push notification..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want to open your app and perform a specific action [while backgrounded], set click_action in the notification payload and map it to an intent filter in the Activity you want to launch. For example, set click_action to OPEN_ACTIVITY_1 to trigger an intent filter like the following:**

As suggested in react-native-fcm docs,ask backend   to send json data in the form like this,

```
 {

    "to":"some_device_token",

    "content_available": true, 
    "notification": {
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "yo",
    "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" // for intent filter in your activity
    },

"data": {
"extra":"juice"
}
}
```

and in your mainfest file add intent-filter for your activity as below

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

When you click the notification, it will open the app and go straight to activity that you define in click_action, in this case "OPEN_ACTIVTY_1". And inside that activity you can get the data by :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();// add these lines of code to get data from notification
String someData = b.getString("someData");
```

check out below links for more helps:

[Firebase FCM notifications click_action payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407366/firebase-fcm-notifications-click-action-payload)

[Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

[Firebase console: How to specify click_action for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111339/firebase-console-how-to-specify-click-action-for-notifications)

Comment: +1 for explaining about intent-filter setting up with action and category to work click_action. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i got this issue long ago. let me check my project code.

Ahh its here.

Try with setting flags

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,    MainActivity.class));       
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and change your `PendingIntent` like below

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ,
                intent, 0);
```

Also remove

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

from your MainActivity from Manifest file

try this and let see it works.