# How to send Push Notification With Custom Click Action From Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload, firebase-console

I'm going to send push notification with custom click action to set `onClick` of notification to open an exact `Activity` in my project when the app is in foreground or background. In all posts and comments it is written that it is impossible to send notification with custom click action from console, but in "Advanced options" in console, it is possible to set custom data keys and values.

[image: Firebase Console]

Why it should be impossible to set `click_action` key and its value?

If it is possible so tell me what should I do. I mean what is the exact intent-filter code? and what should I set as `click_action` value?

Assume that I want to open `SecondActivity` by clicking on notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase FCM notifications click\_action payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407366/firebase-fcm-notifications-click-action-payload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can't send notification like this from the firebase console but this is how it works
you need to add `intent_filter` to the activity at the `manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.MyActivty_TARGET" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and put your `click_action` value as the activity action : `com.mypackage.MyActivty_TARGET"`

and you read the data from the android like this :

```
String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
Intent in = new Intent(click_action);
```

Comment: What's your idea about [Micha F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38149137/6444297)'s solution? _the answer that was accepted by the author of this question just states that it is not possible with Firebase Console, but it is - with an easy workaround,_ **Micha Said**

Comment: This solution will never working when sent notification on fcm console when app is background or killed. Because with notification, fcm auto display the notification without export to trigger in the `onMessageReceived` method. So you cannot do this ```String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
Intent in = new Intent(click_action);```

Comment: @PhanSinh and what can you do to handle the click for push notification when the app is in background then? Is this possible to send data to the exact activity you want to open?

Comment: No, it is not how the Firebase console works.
The click_action provided in the console will not be part of the notification object and it can not be catch with a getClickAction().