# Android- Firebase push notification click event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've followed this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/38149137/6795758 to handle click_action and it works perfectly when app is closed. But when app is opened and if I push notification, app crashes showing the below error:

```
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexo, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.unparcel()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:182)
                                                                                   at android.content.Intent.putExtras(Intent.java:7098)
                                                                                   at com.seven.sample.fcm.ClickActionHelper.startActivity(ClickActionHelper.java:20)
                                                                                   at com.seven.sample.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:33)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Below are my codes of ClickActionHelper class and FirebaseMessaging service

ClickActionHelper.java

```
public class ClickActionHelper {

public static void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context){
    Class cls;

    try {
            cls = Class.forName(className);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
            i.putExtras(extras);
            context.startActivity(i);


    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("NotificationError",e.getMessage());
        //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
    }

 }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {

    Map<String, String> data = message.getData();
    if (data.containsKey("click_action")) {
        ClickActionHelper.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), null, this);
    }

    String image = message.getNotification().getIcon();
    String title = message.getNotification().getTitle();
    String text = message.getNotification().getBody();
    String sound = message.getNotification().getSound();

    int id = 0;
    Object obj = message.getData().get("id");
    if (obj != null) {
        id = Integer.valueOf(obj.toString());
    }

    this.sendNotification(new NotificationData(image, id, title, text, sound));
}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param notificationData GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(NotificationData notificationData) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingPage.class);
    intent.putExtra(notificationData.getTitle(), notificationData.getTextMessage());

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
    try {

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Sample")
                .setContentText(notificationData.getTextMessage()+"")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (notificationBuilder != null) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationData.getId(), notificationBuilder.build());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "NotificationBuilder");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You must be creating the new NotidicationData object with some null parameters. Put some logs inside onMessageReceived method to see if every variable (image, id, title, text, sound) are initialized and not null.

Comment: You're passing a `null` Bundle to your ClickActionHelper then trying to put it in your extras. This might be causing the NPE. Try adding a null checker before adding the bundle and see if you could still encounter the issue.

Comment: thanks  @AL that helped

Comment: You're welcome. Did that solve the issue? I could put in an answer so that we could tag your post as answered. Cheers!

Comment: @AL yes it did..thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onMessageReceived()`, you're calling `startActivity()`:

```
ClickActionHelper.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), null, this);
```

passing a `null` bundle then inserting it in your intent extras:

```
i.putExtras(extras);
```

which is causing the NPE.